# How to receive JSON array?

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api

Help me, please with receiving some JSON array

If i sent request(by Fiddler) with Request Body like this:

[{"name":"Homerius", "tonumber":"155555", "fromnumber":"166666", "text":"&&??!"}, {"name":"Stone", "tonumber":"9654999", "fromnumber":"999666", "text":"h9miii99!"}]

how can I receive it in controller?

I try to do something like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(JObject[] smspackage)
{
    List<MySMS> smses = smspackage.ToList<MySMS>();
    try
    {
        SMS_Repository.Add(smses);
        return Request.CreateResponse<MySMS>(HttpStatusCode.Created, smses);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, "error");
    }
}
```

but it dont works...

*sorry for my bad english*

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(List<MySMS> smses)
{
    try
    {
        SMS_Repository.Add(smses);
        return Request.CreateResponse<List<MySMS>>(HttpStatusCode.Created, smses);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, "error");
    }
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(JArray smspackage)
{
    List<MySMS> smses = smspackage.ToObject<List<MySMS>>();

    ... snip ...
}
```

Comment: alternative variant gives exception in method  public HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext):                                                                  var selectedAction = _innerSelector.SelectAction(controllerContext);

Comment: I've tested out the solution with the information that you have provided and it works for me. The errors you are getting may be more to do with your routing and action selection. I suggest you open a new question and supply your full routing and controller code.

Comment: It works, both variants! Thanks, I don't know why it didn't work before. It very easy, as it turns out.